# Получение данных в браузере только от доверенного сайта

Tags: браузер

Как реализовать получение данных в браузере Google Chrome или ином браузере только от доверенного сайта?

К примеру Я, как пользователь браузера захожу на сайт: [goldenscrew.net](http://goldenscrew.net/), и хочу получать информацию, размещенную только на данном домене.
Не хочу получать, информацию, скрипты, css, картинки, видео и т. д., расположенную на других доменах, отличных от домена goldenscrew.net, таких как google.com, vk.com, metrika.yandex.ru и т. п.
[image: Не хочу загружать информацию...]

Comment: Через плагины типа adblock и ghostery вырезаются из кода подобные штуки. А на уровне настроек браузера я не видел еще :)

Comment: То есть вас устроит, что при этом сайт может поломаться целиком?

Comment: @gil9red устану Я всё прописывать, мне бы наоборот, разрешить доступ а не запрещать. Разрешить доступ к сайту, а чтобы остальное всё блокировалось.

Comment: @andreymal да, устроит.

Answer (score 0):

Для FireFox есть NoScript — расширение, блокирующее исполнение JavaScript, апплетов Java, Flash и других потенциально опасных компонентов HTML-страниц до тех пор, пока пользователь не разрешит их исполнение на данном узле или глобально.

Для Chrome есть аналоги, ScriptSafe например.

Comment: данный способ блокирует только потенциально опасные моменты, мне нужна блокировка всей сторонней информации

Comment: @GoldenScrew NoScript вообще все скрипты блокирует кроме тех которые вы сами разрешите.

Comment: речь не о скриптах, а обо всём контенте.